# Different DOBs on passport and birth certificate: does that cause any problems?

Tags: usa, immigration, greencard

I recently applied for the US DV Lottery (DV-2021). In the application process I wrote everything (including DOB) as written on my passport. But the problem is I have a different DOB written on my birth certificate. Now that I have been selected for further processing, does that cause any problems?

The DOB on the passport is written as 01/01/1996, while the correct DOB (on the birth certificate) is written as 14/06/1991. I am not sure if this is relevant so I added it. In both cases, the age is above 21 years.

Comment: How is it that you have a different date of birth on your birth certificate. Is it because of mm/dd/yyyy <-> dd/mm/yyyy confusion (something I've run into)?

Comment: No, the dates are completely different. I will edit accordingly.

Comment: Ok, so the question is (and likely the first question asked by anybody having to deal with this case), how is it that these dates are different? That's a pretty remarkable difference that isn't easily explained away as some sort of clerical error. You didn't notice this difference in your passport?

Comment: I did notice and asked asked them to get it corrected. They refused due to the fact that this is the date they have in their records, which most likely is just an estimate they did. Back then such records were kept on paper. When I applied for the passport, they didn't have the paper records, so they estimated my DOB.

Comment: It will be an issue, but they have seen this sort of thing before with certain nationalities. As long as your explanation is consistent with that, I think you will be alright. I am surprised that your actual birth certificate doesn't trump their 'estimate'. But some bureaucracies just have that kind of attitude. BTW, you must look awfully young for them to have shaved off 5+ years like that!